# How to get data from javascript and show on php

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in javascript coding.
I dont know why i cannot see data on my php script. 
I want to check data from my mysql if exsist in database and then get value in php script.
Only i see is data on  wich i dont need.
Later i will use this in joomla article, so if there is any other way to
make code or mybe any example i will be happy to learn.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form1" action="form_action.asp">

    <input type="radio" checked value="1" name="RegionType" /> OPTION 1<br>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="RegionType" /> OPTION 2<br>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="RegionType" /> OPTION 3<br><br>
    OPTION 4: <input type="text" id="regionname" name="regionname" value="" size="25" maxlength="15"><br>
    OPTION 5: <input type="text" id="positionx" name="positionx" value="" size="25" maxlength="4"><br>
    OPTION 6: <input type="text" id="positiony" name="positiony" value="" size="25" maxlength="4"><br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="STEP 2">
</form> 

<span id="type"></span><br>
<span id="name"></span><br>
<span id="posx"></span><br>
<span id="posy"></span>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var RN = document.getElementById("regionname").value;
    var PX = document.getElementById("positionx").value;
    var PY = document.getElementById("positiony").value;
    var RegionType = document.forms[0];
    var txt = "";
    var i;

        for (i = 0; i < RegionType.length; i++) {
            if (RegionType[i].checked) {
                txt = txt + RegionType[i].value + " ";
            }           
        }    

    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = txt;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = RN; 
    document.getElementById("posx").innerHTML = PX; 
    document.getElementById("posy").innerHTML = PY; 


}
</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php

    $TXT = $_GET['txt '];
    echo "$TXT";

    $RN = $_GET['RN '];
    echo "$RN";

    $PX = $_GET['PX '];
    echo "$PX";

    $PY = $_GET['PY '];
    echo "$PY";

?>
```

Comment: so there comes a term Ajax use jquery ajax

Comment: [AJAX 101 w/ jQuery](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: php + .asp :/ ...

Answer (score 1):

What you don't seem to know is that Javascript code is run on client side (in the browser) after the website code was returned by the server.

So this is the order of the magic things that happen:
- Client requests the site (somesite.php)
- The server processes the request and returns the site "created" by PHP (including the Javascript code)
- The browser displays the site and runs the Javascript code

In other words: In your example the PHP code is run (on server side) before any Javascript action happens (client side).
If you want some Javascript generated data be processed by PHP, you have to send it to the server via a request. This is what AJAX can be used for.
Maybe this is an interesting example for you:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

So if i understund right. 
I must make one file .php wich will connect to database and see if there is data in. But i dont understund how do use value from input form in php code?

Comment: The input data will be sent with the requests. If you use a form in your website it will either be available in the $_GET or the $_POST variable in PHP (depending on the forms method). 
Using `<form action="test.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="vari" /><input type="submit" value="send!" /></form>` the value for "vari" will be availabe as $_POST["vari"] in test.php.

Comment: Sorry but i must do all this in one file, because i use joomla and plugin sourcerer.

Comment: No problem. Just leave the form's action attribute empty and the same page will be requested.
`<form action="" method="post"> ...`